# If $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence in $[a,b]$ and $R$ its range. If $h$ is bounded $ \implies h\chi_R$ integrable in $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b h\chi_R=0$

Tags: calculus, integration

If $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence in $[a,b]$ and $R$ its range. Prove that if $h$ is a bounded function in $[a,b] \implies  h\chi_R$ is integrable in $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b h\chi_R=0$

Here is what I got so far:

$g=h\chi_R$ is bounded. Consider the partition of $[a,b] \ P_n=\{a,a+\frac{b-a}{n},a+\frac{2(b-a)}{n},...,b\}$.

As there is no sequence which all the range is $[a,b]$. Then $R \subset [a,b]$, i.e, in all interval $I_j$ defined by $P_n, \ \exists x_j\in R$ such that $g(x_j)=h(x_j)\chi_R=0$

Without loss of generality, assume that $g(x)\geq0$, then:

1. $L(h\chi_R,P_n)=\sum m_j(h\chi_R,P_n)\Delta X_j=\sum 0 \cdot \frac{1}{n}=0$
2. $U(h\chi_R,P_n)=\sum M_j(h\chi_R,P_n)\Delta X_j=\sum_{x_j\in R}h(x_j)\cdot \frac{1}{n}+\sum_{x_j\notin R}0 \cdot \frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{x_j\in R}h(x_j)$

How can I continue?

Comment: And also state if you deal with Riemann or Lebesgue integral.

Comment: It's Riemman!
And I am guessing that the rank is the difference between the highest and lowest numbers of the sequence

Comment: The correct word was range, my bad, translated the wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ converges to $a$. If the limit is $c \in (a,b)$ you can consider $\int_a^c$ and $\int_c^b$.

For all $0 \lt \epsilon \lt b-a$, $R \cap (a+\epsilon,b)$ is finite as $\{x_n\}$ converges to $a$. $\int_{a+\epsilon}^b h \chi_R = 0$  as $h \chi_R$ is always vanishing except at a finite number of points on the interval $[a+\epsilon,b]$.

If $h$ is bounded by $M >0$, you have $-m \le h\chi_R \le M$ on $[a, a + \epsilon]$.

Based on the two previous arguments, build a partition $P_n \equiv x_1 = a < x_2 = a + \epsilon < x_3 < \dots < x_n=b$ and upper and lower maps such that the difference of the upper and lower Darboux sums ar less that $3M \epsilon$.

As this is true for all $\epsilon >0$, you can conclude that $h \chi_R$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and that its integral is equal to zero.